# Django 1.10: Commit data to log table after fail / rollback of main transaction

Tags: django, transactions

I am moving to Django 1.10 from Django 1.5 and discovering that database transactions are quite different with little commit and rollback control.

What I want:

```
Perform series of queries in view: my_function(request)
If all queries succeed:
    commit
if any query fails:
   rollback
   insert into log table and commit the insertion
```

In Django 1.5, I handle this with rollback and commit in the Exception Middleware:

```
class ExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception): 
        # do rollback
        # insert into log table
        # commit
```

How can I achieve this in Django 1.10 where there doesn't seem to be a way to do rollback?

My 1.10 settings:

```
AUTOCOMMIT = True
ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True
```

This puts all queries into a single transaction that, correctly, only commits upon completion.

I would have more rollback/commit control with "AUTOCOMMIT = False," but Django recommends against this: "this is best used in situations where you want to run your own transaction-controlling middleware or do something really strange."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked. When there is an exception in my_view(), its insertion is rolled back, but the insertion in the exception middleware is committed.

settings.py

```
Database ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'myproject.middleware.ExceptionMiddleware', # put it last
]
```

views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    do table insertion insertion..
    x = 1/0 # cause exception
```

middleware.py

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class ExceptionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception): 
        # can be put inside "with transaction.atomic():" for more control of rollback/commit within this function
        log_error() # do table insertion
        # can return some response
```

Comment: Yes, so we use this

Answer (score 2):

Django 1.10 also introduced a new style of middleware, which makes this quite easy:

```
from django.db import transaction

class LoggingMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                response = self.get_response(request)
        except:
            log_failure()
            raise
        return response
```

When an exception is propagated through the `__exit__` method of `transaction.atomic()`, the transaction is automatically rolled back. You can then catch the exception and log the failure outside of the main transaction that encapsulates the view.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try and report back :)

Comment: And `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` can be set to `False`.

Comment: This didn't work. An exception in the view was never caught by the Middleware exception handler. I tried putting LoggingMiddleware at both the top and bottom of the middleware stack in settings.py. I checked that LoggingMiddleware IS called by being able to set the response to something different (and seeing that returned) when there was no exception in the view.